# Image Captions Have a 10px Extra Margin, And It's Not CSS?

Tags: images, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Caption in Page adding unwanted 10px to width](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14305/caption-in-page-adding-unwanted-10px-to-width)

This is a screen capture from a post.  I have given .wp-caption a black background so the extra 10px margin on the right can be seen.  The 10px margin on the top is purposeful.  **I don't know what is causing the 10px margin on the right and there is nothing else I can find in my code that would create it... I've even eliminated everything in my CSS to rid it of this margin but it still remains.**

One solution is to set the image width to 100%, but this adds an adittional 10 pixels to my assigned image size in my posts and therefore makes the image distorted horizontally by 10 pixels.  **This problem is only happening with captions, not general images.**

You can see the problem here: http://themeforward.com/demo2/sample-elements/

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/217/prob1c.jpg/]

```
/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
//  30. Images
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
img {
    border:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:5!important
}
#post_content img, p img {
    height:auto;
    z-index:5!important;
    max-width:650px;
    margin-top:9px!important
}
#content img {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    max-width:100%!important
}

/* Images - Aligning */
.aligncenter {
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto 10px
}
.alignleft {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin:0 25px 10px 0
}
.alignright {
    display:block;
    float:right;
    margin:0 0 10px 25px
}

/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
//  31. Image captions
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
.wp-caption img {
    border:none;
height:auto;
    background:#F5F5F5;
    max-width:650px!important
    }
.wp-caption p.wp-caption-text {
    font-size:85%;
    padding:0!important;
    margin:2px 0 5px!important;
    line-height:175%!important;
    font-style:italic;
    text-align:left
}
.wp-caption { background:#000 }

/* Image Captions */
.alignleft.wp-caption { margin:0 25px 10px 0 }
.alignright.wp-caption { margin:9px 0 10px 25px }
.aligncenter.wp-caption { }
```

Comment: can you share your site link?

Comment: http://themeforward.com/demo2/sample-elements/

Comment: The image shortcode adds a `+10` inline width value to the caption div, see [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-includes/media.php#L710). It's that inline width setting on the div that is the source of your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer, in functions.php

```
function wpse14305_img_caption( $empty_string, $attributes, $content ){
  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'id' => '',
    'align' => 'alignnone',
    'width' => '',
    'caption' => ''
  ), $attributes));
  if ( empty($caption) )
    return $content;
  if ( $id ) $id = 'id="' . esc_attr($id) . '" ';
  return '<div ' . $id . 'class="wp-caption ' . esc_attr($align) . '">' . do_shortcode( $content ) . '<p class="wp-caption-text">' . $caption . '</p></div>';
}

add_filter( 'img_caption_shortcode', 'wpse14305_img_caption', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: I've found a neater solution, it's posted under the original question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120580/20311

Answer (score 1):

Fancybox (or some other javascript / jQuery element) is setting the width of the image in your markup. If you look at Firebug, you'll see the div element width as 471px, which is 10px wider than your image width.

Comment: It's WordPress - The image shortcode adds a `+10` inline width value to the caption div, see [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-includes/media.php#L710). That'll be the source of the extra width.. ;)

Comment: @t31os - so how do I fix it?

Comment: Run a filter on the shortcode and reduce the width value by 10 or use some CSS to target that specific div and reduce the width.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`.alignleft.wp-caption {
margin: 0 25px 10px 0;
}`

to

`.alignleft.wp-caption {
margin: 0 25px 10px 0;
width: 461px !important;
}`